# how to get the filname for fileupload control from dropdownlist? asp .net with c#

Tags: file-upload, drop-down-menu

asp .net with c#...In dropdownlist I have filename * filepath...If i select a file name means that file name have to assign to fileupload control

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You can't retain/assign value in FileUpload control. This is because of due to browser security reasons.

You can make use of label control to display path intead of the fileupload control.